# CMake cannot find GLEW (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: cmake, compilation, glew

I am attempting to compile https://github.com/ad044/lain-bootleg-bootleg on Ubuntu 22.04 and have run into an issue where CMake can't find some components of `glew`.

I have pointed `GLEW_LIBRARY` and `GLEW_INCLUDE` already but I am unable to find the path for `GLEW_LIBRARIES`. I was wondering if someone here knows what that path is so that I may include it in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Here is CMake's output:

```
-- Checking for module 'glew'
--   No package 'glew' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_LIBRARIES) (found version "")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:215 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package)
```

For what it's worth, I have attempted the dev version of `glew-utils` and it did not resolve the issue.

What do I need I set for `set(GLEW_LIBRARIES "directory_here")`?

Comment: "I have pointed GLEW_LIBRARY and GLEW_INCLUDE already" - You shouldn't do that in the first place. As you could find from the documentation of [FindGLEW.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLEW.html), the only variables which the module expects from a user are `GLEW_USE_STATIC_LIBS` and `GLEW_VERBOSE`. If you have GLEW installed system-wide (e.g. by installing `libglew-dev` package on Ubuntu), then CMake should be able to find the library automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while trying to compile valkka-core which also could not find glew despite it being installed. I had to `sudo apt install freeglut3-dev` in order to resolve the issue.

I used this small CMakeLists.txt file in its own folder to debug the issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GLEW glew)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

Then if you run `cmake CMakeLists.txt` this will help you quickly see if the issue is resolved rather than running a big project's full one which could take some time.

For posterity: the other error I found related to this issue said glu requires OpenGL but could not find it.